# How create a webscript that return the output progressively?

Tags: java, http, spring-web

We have a really long process an we want to trigger that progress with a webscript's endpoint

But because it is too long with too many steps, we want to write in the body the steps accomplished and I want them to be display into the client browser meanwhile the are created.

I tried flushing the outputStream, but that doesn't render the output into the browser inmediatly. The browser waits until all the steps finish for displaying the output

```
public class ProgressiveProcessWebscript implements AbstractWebScript 
    public final void execute(WebScriptRequest request, 
         WebScriptResponse response) {
       ...
       response.setContentType(MIMETYPE_TXT);

       OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
       FilterOutputStream filterOutputStream = new FilterOutputStream(output);

       for (Step step: stepList) {
          step.execute();
          filterOutputStream.write(step.getName().getBytes());
          filterOutputStream.flush();
       }
```

WebScriptResponse

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply write to the `OutputStream` and flush it. You must implement another concept. There is different solutions for your problem.

You should take a look to this great post: [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

The Ajax Long Polling solution is in my opinion probably the easiest way, since you don't need any other framework server-side.

Comment: then there is no way to do it just with a simple http request?